# OAuth2: Is the `auth_time` claim tied to the refresh token expiration?

Tags: authentication, oauth, oauth-2.0, openid-connect, refresh-token

If I know that my auth provider sets refresh tokens to expire after twelve hours, and I have authenticated and my `auth_time` claim shows as 9AM today, can I safely assume that at 9PM tonight my refresh token will expire?  Or are `auth_time` and refresh token issuance/expiration independent of one another?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on the auth provider, but in some providers you can set difference expire times on the different tokens (id/access/refresh). Also some supports absolute or sliding expiration times.

Sample expire config options for IdentityServer can be found [here](https://identityserver4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/client.html?highlight=expire%20times) for inspiration.